# Can I have Windows prompt me before shutting down?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have a laptop which has the power button on the side, making it very easy to accidentally bump it and shut down my computer while I am using it.  Is there some way I can have Windows display a prompt before shutting down when the power button is pressed?

Note: I know I can change it so that the power button sleeps, hibernates, etc. but that is not what I am asking.  I want the computer to shut down when I hit the power button, but ask me first.

Comment: I don't think there is such an option in the newer Windows versions. But you can change something in the system that you'll get a prompt for the reason for the shutdown. See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/1065968/235723 It works and you can press escape to stop the shutdown.